# I need to calculate the time between two dates in access in working hours

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

I have a formula to do this in Excel, but I want to convert it to Access
I have two dates - start time and end time.  I need to know the number of hours:minutes between them in business hours only.  To take the most complicated senario:

1. Business hours are M-F, 9-5 excluding holidays
2. An event happened at 4:30pm on Friday and ended Tuesday at 10:30am
3. Monday is a holiday
4. The resulting time should be 2 hours

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Typically users here want to see what you've tried to solve your problem, just so it's clear that you aren't asking "Hey, will someone do my work for me?" If you add a little detail showing what you've tried or what ideas you have but don't know how to implement, you're more likely to get upvotes and answers.

Comment: There is a function named DateDiff that you can use:

https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f?ui=en-US&rs=en-SG&ad=SG

Answer (score 0):

If you have a formula in Excel you should be virtually able to put this logic in an Acess query, just change the syntax to accomodate Sql. Likewise just convert you Excel logic into VBA if you must use this. You have the answer in front of you, you just need to convert it into a different language,

Comment: An answer should really be a definitive solution to the question.  It's hard to write a good answer to a nebulous question.  Especially without clarification from the OP, sometimes the best you can do is offer general suggestions on an approach.  The place to do that is in a comment.  Just a heads up that trigger-happy downvoters might see this as "not an answer", which would eat into your rep.  You might want to consider moving this to a comment.  If the OP posts better info and you want to create a solution, do that in an answer.

Comment: I take your point but I don't think the question is that bad given the first sentence says "I have a formula to do this in Excel, but I want to convert it to Access". If he is 100% happy with that Excel formula it should be easy to convert to an Access query or small VBA function. He says enough to make me pretty sure that is the case.

Comment: That's true, but a good answer to any question explains how to implement the solution.  Your answer just says it can be done.  It's a direction to look for an answer, not an actual solution to what was asked.  To provide a good answer to this question, you would need to create a tutorial on how to do the process, which is beyond the scope of the site (which is why it isn't a good question).  Your answer is vulnerable to downvotes.  Just saying.